# Can redis signal to start a python function?

Tags: python, optimization, redis

I need to start a thread from redis list, whenever it is updated

my code goes like this

```py
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
print("Welcome")
while True:
    if r.llen("pre_cert_list"):
        for i in range(r.llen("pre_cert_list")):
            cert_id = r.rpop("pre_cert_list").decode()
            print(cert_id)
            new_thread = CertifyStudent(cert_id, r)
            new_thread.start()
        time.sleep(10)
```

The problem is this method is not efficient. I would to like to know if there is any way find if the value is added to redis

something like this

```
redis.signal.send('key')
```

for setting the signal, which would call this code

```
if redis.signal.recive('key'):
   do stuff
```

Comment: The answer to your question is **yes it can**. If you wish to obtain a more detailed answer you should be more specific. If you are unsure about how to be more specific have a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: hi @jojo thanks for response,  have edited my post plz check it out, plz share any methods that you may have